# Failed validate dynamic filefields in Yii?

Tags: php, validation, yii, filefield

**Hi, I'm trying to validate active filefield fields that were created in Yii so dynamic.**

I build using a forech for this inputs, the question is that when trying to validate when the user selects an image, indicate whether the file you chose is above the allowed weight, and also if it is a correct file format.

But i don't know that I'm doing wrong.

I tried this:
***My model***

```
public $image;
public function tableName() {
    return 'vrf_image';
}

/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules() {
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('id_form', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        // Pruebas para subir imagen
            // Inicio
            array(
                'image',
                'file',
                'types'=>'jpg, gif, png',
                'allowEmpty'=>true,
                'on'=>'update',
                'on'=>'insert',
                'wrongType'=>'Solo imagenes',

                'mimeTypes' => 'image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png',
                'wrongMimeType' => 'Invalid mime type',

                'maxSize'=>1024*1024*2,
                'tooLarge'=>'File has to be smaller than 2MB',
            ),
            array(
                'image',
                'length',
                'max'=>50,
                'on'=>'insert,update'
            ),
            array(
                'id, image, id_form, id_ques',
                'safe',
                'on'=>'search'
            ),
        // Fin
    );
}
```

***My views***

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row paddings_bottom">
<?php
    $hoho = VrfImage::model()->findAll("id_form = $search->id");

    $formImage=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'verification-form-image',
        'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl("backendVerification/default/CreateImage?id=".$modUser->id),
        'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array(
            'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
            'validateOnChange'=>true,
            'validateOnType'=>true,
        ),
    ));
?>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
            <?php
                $oo = 0; $ban = 0;
                foreach ($numQues as $ii => $NQ){
                    if($ii==0){
                        echo '<div class="borTopFormVrf"><span class="White">Company Documentation</span></div>';
                    }
                    if($ii <6){
                    if($oo<2){
                        if($oo==0){
                            echo '<tr>';
                        }
            ?>
                            <td class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 nopadd" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
                                <?php
                                    foreach ($hoho as $key => $value) {
                                        if($hoho[$key]->id_ques == $NQ){
                                            echo '<img src="'.getThemeUri().'/../../VerificationResource/images/'.$hoho[$key]->image.'" style="max-width:100%;">';
                                            $ban = 1;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if($ban!=1){ echo '<img src="#" style="max-width:100%; visibility: hidden;" id="img_prev'.$ii.'" alt="your image"/>'; }
                                    else{ $ban=0; }
                                ?>
                                <?php echo $form->HiddenField($modImage,"[".$ii."]id_ques",array('value'=>$NQ)); ?>
                                <?php echo $formImage->fileField($modImage,'['.$ii.']image', array('class'=>'form-control Borf-c', 'onChange'=>'readURL(this,'.$ii.')')); ?>
                                <?php echo $formImage->error($modImage,'['.$ii.']image'); ?>
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <?php echo $nameQues[$ii]; ?>
                                </div>
                            </td>
            <?php       if($oo==1){ echo '</tr>'; $oo = -1; }
                        $oo++;
                    }}
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 divTopFormBVrf">
            <?php
                if(isset($search->id_verifier)){
                    if($search->id_verifier == userID()){
                        echo CHtml::submitButton('Save', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn_create_address btn_create_address_size'));
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
```

***In my controller***

```
public function actionCreateImage($id) {
    $form = VrfForm::model()->find("id_user = $id");

    $path_picture = realpath(Yii::app()->getBasePath()."/../VerificationResource/images")."/"; //ruta final de la imagen

    if(isset($_POST['VrfImage'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['VrfImage'] as $key => $value) {
            $modImage = new VrfImage;
            $modImage->attributes = $value;
            //print_r($modImage->validate());
            if($modImage->validate()){
                echo 'Correcto';
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                $rnd = rand(0,9999);  // generar números aleatorios entre 0-9999
                $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($modImage,'['.$key.']image');
                $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";  // número aleatorio + nombre de archivo, o se puede usar: $fileName=$uploadedFile->getName();

                if(!empty($uploadedFile)) { // Compruebe si el archivo se ha subido o no.
                    $uploadedFile->saveAs($path_picture.$fileName);
                    $modImage->image = $fileName;
                    $modImage->id_ques = $value['id_ques'];
                    $modImage->id_form = $form->id;

                    if($modImage->save()) {
                        //echo ' REVISA!!! <br>';
                    }
                    else{
                        echo $modImage->error();
                    }
                }
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }
            else{
                echo 'Falla';
                //$this->redirect($this->createUrl('default/Form'));
            }
        }
    }
    //$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl.'backendVerification/default/Form?id='.$id);
}
```

**But don't It does not work.!!!**

**Is bad my "clientOptions" in the form?**
**Is bad my rules in the model?**

**Help T.T**

Answer (score 0):

Well, I knew not to use Yii to achieve validate my fields. It will not be the best way, but I ended up with this for the validation I needed.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row paddings_bottom">
<?php
    $hoho = VrfImage::model()->findAll("id_form = $search->id");

    $formImage=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'verification-form-image',
        'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl("backendVerification/default/CreateImage?id=".$modUser->id),
        'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array(
            'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
            'validateOnChange'=>true,
            'validateOnType'=>true,
        ),
    ));
?>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
            <?php
                $numQues = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,111,222,333];
                $nameQues = ['Business license','Company code','Tax register','Export license','Joint venture approved certificate','Land certificate','ISO9001:2008','ISO14001;2004','UL certificate','CE certificate','Quality manual','Quality organization'];
                $oo = 0; $ban = 0;
                foreach ($numQues as $ii => $NQ){
                    if($ii==0){
                        echo '<div class="borTopFormVrf"><span class="White">Company Documentation</span></div>';
                    }
                    if($ii <6){
                    if($oo<2){
                        if($oo==0){
                            echo '<tr>';
                        }
            ?>
                            <td class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 nopadd" style="border: 1px solid #000;">

                                <?php
                                    foreach ($hoho as $key => $value) {
                                        if($hoho[$key]->id_ques == $NQ){
                                            echo '<img src="'.getThemeUri().'/../../VerificationResource/images/'.$hoho[$key]->image.'" style="max-width:100%;">';
                                            $ban = 1;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if($ban!=1){
                                        echo '<img src="#" style="visibility: hidden;" id="img_prev'.$ii.'" alt="your image"/>';
                                    }
                                    else{ $ban=0; }
                                ?>
                                <?php echo $form->HiddenField($modImage,"[".$ii."]id_ques",array('value'=>$NQ)); ?>
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #000;">
                                    <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7">
                                        <?php echo $formImage->fileField($modImage,'['.$ii.']image', array( 'onChange'=>'readURL(this,'.$ii.')')); ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                                        <?php
                                        if($ban!=1){
                                            echo '<label id="lbl'.$ii.'" style="visibility: hidden;" onclick="kkk('.$ii.')">X</label>';
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <?php echo $formImage->error($modImage,'['.$ii.']image'); ?>
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <?php echo $nameQues[$ii]; ?>
                                </div>
                            </td>
            <?php       if($oo==1){ echo '</tr>'; $oo = -1; }
                        $oo++;
                    }}
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 MT15">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <?php
                if(isset($search->id_verifier)){
                    if($search->id_verifier == userID()){
                        echo CHtml::submitButton('Save', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn_formVrf btn_create_address_size GreenVrf'));
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
```

And later this with function js:

```
function readURL(input,num) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        if(input.files[0].type=='image/jpeg' || input.files[0].type=='image/gif' || input.files[0].type=='image/png'){
            if(input.files[0].size>1000000){
                $('#VrfImage_'+num+'_image').val('');
                alert("El archivo supera el peso permitido (1MB)");
                return false;
            }
            else{
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#img_prev'+num).css('visibility','visible');
                    $('#img_prev'+num).attr('src', e.target.result).width(250).height(250);
                    $('#lbl'+num).css('visibility','visible');
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);   
            }
        }
        else{
            $('#VrfImage_'+num+'_image').val('');
            alert("El archivo no es una imagen valida\n(debe ser JPG, JPEG, GIF o PNG y pesar maximo 1MB.)");
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function kkk(num){
    $('#img_prev'+num).css('visibility','hidden');
    $('#img_prev'+num).css('height','27px');
    $('#VrfImage_'+num+'_image').val('');
    $('#lbl'+num).css('visibility','hidden');
}
```